# Is it possible to customize the keyboard in .net maui for android application?

Tags: android, .net, maui, keyboard-layout, android-custom-keyboard

I have been working in a .NET MAUI in visual studio for an android application.
we need to customize the keyboard layout by our own type.
can someone help us on this!!

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It might be like xamarin forms - google `xamarin forms custom keyboard android`. However, instead of a xamarin "custom renderer", read docs about creating a maui "handler".

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the technique used in xamarin to fully customize the keyboard? Because it seems the KeyboardView has been deprecated from API 29 and the only way to do it is by copying the java files from Google. Also would those method be applicable to MAUI ?